# SqlDataSource update statement for converting string to dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview and a `SqlDataSource`.

In the `SqlDataSource`'s update statement I'm trying to convert the string of the column to datetime with this:

```
Date = Convert(DateTime, @Date, 104) 
//this converts the string to mm.dd.yyyy .
```

I can't find the code for `mm.dd.yyyy hh:mm .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions states you are using a GridView and a DataSource.

I'm assuming your source data is in a DateTime format in SQL Server.
If so, leave it in that format, otherwise, cast it as a DateTime when returning it.

Do **NOT** try converting it into a string on the SQL Server end *or* run a pass over your DataTable and convert it to a string using C#.  That is the wrong approach to this.

All you need to do is set the *DataFormatString* on your GridView's BoundField column like so:

```
BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.DataField = "xxxxx";//The field from your DataSource you are binding to.
bf.HeaderText = "yyyyy";//The column header text of your GridView.
bf.DataFormatString = "{0:MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm}";
gv.Columns.Add(bf);//Add the column to your GridView.
```

Comment: I should also add that, by doing this way, if you enable sorting then it will work correctly.  If you pass in a string value representing the date, it will sort on that string value (and in your case) it would be incorrect as it will sort on Month and Day before Year.

Comment: sorry to interject here but I could not comment on the answer you deleted. Obviously I wasn't the only one who thought your answer was incorrect, and the point of down-voting is to show you that it is incorrect and allow you the chance to fix it. Once you fix it the down-vote can be un-done and converted to an up-vote. But an incorrect answer can't be left with no down-votes as other readers may think it is correct (they won't necessarily read the comments). I've up-voted this answer as a sign of good faith. Also you weren't helping me, it wasn't my question.

Answer (score 1):

to display it in the grid with the wanted format, use `yourDate.ToString(yourFormat)`, example:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("mm.dd.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime MyDateTime;

MyDateTime = new DateTime();
MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(varchar(17),Date,113)
```

Use this and it ll get, 29 Nov 2011 12:58

Or use this;

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(17),OrderDate,105)+' '+CONVERT(varchar(17),OrderDate,108) as Date FROM Orders
```

It ll be ; 29-11-2011 12:58:48